# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'history_change_reason'

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I am saving change history on every change in django model by using django-simple-history.

that what I tried:

```py
class MyModel(models.models):
    field1 = ...
    ...
    history = HistoricalRecords(
        history_change_reason_field=models.TextField(null=True)
    )


name = 'xyz'
for doc_id, status in my_data:
    reporting , _ = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(
        doc_id=doc_id,
        user=self.request.user
    )
    reporting.is_accepted = status
    reporting.save(
        update_fields=['is_accepted']
    )
    update_change_reason(
        instance=reporting,
        reason=f'Change request done by {name}'
    )
```

and I got below error.
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'history_change_reason'`

Comment: I think the problem is occurring because you are saving the object before setting the `history_change_reason`. Because the check occurs on save, at that moment the reason is not present and error is shown.

Comment: `update_change_reason` requires a model instance as the first argument. If I don't save then the model instance not found and throw an error.